# Why DESC ordered query slow on MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb, query-optimization

I have this query that running against Maridb, when we query in ASC order, the optimizer examing less amount of records(r_rows) and completes the query in ~500 milliseconds, but when switching the order by to DESC then the same query taking more time to complete and r_rows going ~2.27 million.

Why is that? Why is ASC/DESC order impacting query performance?

**Here is the SQL Query**

```
SELECT x_nuvo_eam_scheduled_m9e_e8s0.`sys_id`
FROM (
        x_nuvo_eam_scheduled_m9e_e8s x_nuvo_eam_scheduled_m9e_e8s0
        LEFT JOIN x_nuvo_eam_scheduled_m10s x_nuvo_eam_scheduled_maintena1 ON x_nuvo_eam_scheduled_m9e_e8s0.`scheduled_maintenance` = x_nuvo_eam_scheduled_maintena1.`sys_id`
    )
WHERE x_nuvo_eam_scheduled_m9e_e8s0.`status` = 'Pending'
    AND x_nuvo_eam_scheduled_m9e_e8s0.`scheduled_date` >= '2022-02-15 06:00:00'
    AND x_nuvo_eam_scheduled_maintena1.`asset` IS NULL
ORDER BY x_nuvo_eam_scheduled_m9e_e8s0.`sys_created_on` ASC
limit 0, 100
```

**Below 2 MariaDB Analyze output that shows to the execution plan**

ASC ordered Query Completes ~503 ms

```
+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                                                                             1 result(s):                                         
+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| ANALYZE | {                                                                                                                      
|         |   "query_block": {                                                                                                     
|         |     "select_id": 1,                                                                                                    
|         |     "r_loops": 1,                                                                                                      
|         |     "r_total_time_ms": 503.93,                                                                                         
|         |     "table": {                                                                                                         
|         |       "table_name": "Table_A",                                                                                         
|         |       "access_type": "index",                                                                                          
|         |       "possible_keys": ["idx1"],                                                                                       
|         |       "key": "sys_created_on",                                                                                         
|         |       "key_length": "6",                                                                                               
|         |       "used_key_parts": ["sys_created_on"],                                                                            
|         |       "r_loops": 1,                                                                                                    
|         |       "rows": 2695302,                                                                                                 
|         |       "r_rows": 234328,                                                                                                
|         |       "r_total_time_ms": 476.64,                                                                                       
|         |       "filtered": 50,                                                                                                  
|         |       "r_filtered": 0.1903,                                                                                            
|         |       "attached_condition": "Table_A.`status` = 'Pending' and Table_A.scheduled_date >= '2022-02-15 06:00:00'"         
|         |     },    
+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

DESC ASC ordered Query Completes ~9118 ms

```
r_rows significantly Larger as comparing to ASC. 

+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                                                                             1 result(s):                                        
+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| ANALYZE | {                                                                                                                     
|         |   "query_block": {                                                                                                    
|         |     "select_id": 1,                                                                                                   
|         |     "r_loops": 1,                                                                                                     
|         |     "r_total_time_ms":9118.4,                                                                                              
|         |     "table": {                                                                                                        
|         |       "table_name": "Table_A",                                                                                        
|         |       "access_type": "index",                                                                                         
|         |       "possible_keys": ["idx1"],                                                                                      
|         |       "key": "sys_created_on",                                                                                        
|         |       "key_length": "6",                                                                                              
|         |       "used_key_parts": ["sys_created_on"],                                                                           
|         |       "r_loops": 1,                                                                                                   
|         |       "rows": 2695302,                                                                                                
|         |       "r_rows": 2.27e6,                                                                                               
|         |       "r_total_time_ms": 4380.1,                                                                                      
|         |       "filtered": 50,                                                                                                 
|         |       "r_filtered": 70.102,                                                                                           
|         |       "attached_condition": "Table_A.`status` = 'Pending' and Table_A.scheduled_date >= '2022-02-15 06:00:00'" |
|         |     },  
+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: ```FROM ( Table Table LEFT JOIN Table Table ON Table.`scheduled_maintenance` = Table.`sys_id` )``` o_O What is it??? Provide: real SQL query text; complete CREATE TABLE for datasource, precise MariaDB version.

Comment: All I know is that `TABLE` is a [reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html). In a question like this there should not be any confusion about the table design and the query used.

Comment: like Akina says, please edit your question to show (as text, not images) output of `show create table yourtablename;` for all tables used in the query and `select version();` and `explain select ...` for both queries and your actual query.

Comment: sorry for confusion everyone and thank you. Added the original query, I cannot get the DDL of the tables and already added analyzer output which has more information then explain plan

Comment: And where are **complete** CREATE TABLE scripts (the output for `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;`) for both tables?

Comment: Note [MariaDB-10.8.1](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-1081-release-notes/) supports descending indexes in InnoDB

Answer (score 0):

Index suggestions to optimize

Table                          Index
x_nuvo_eam_scheduled_m9e_e8s   ( status, scheduled_date, scheduled_maintenance, sys_created_on )
x_nuvo_eam_scheduled_m10s      ( sys_id )

Then, revised without (parens) and `ticks`, but also making use of cleaner aliases of scheduled vs maintenance.  The first table having a proper index to optimize on the WHERE and JOIN criteria will help.  But also having the created on to complete the covering index will help the query as all elements can come from the index instead of going back to the raw data pages per table.

```
SELECT 
        sched.sys_id
    FROM 
        x_nuvo_eam_scheduled_m9e_e8s sched
            LEFT JOIN x_nuvo_eam_scheduled_m10s maint
                ON sched.scheduled_maintenance = maint.sys_id
    WHERE 
            sched.status = 'Pending'
        AND sched.scheduled_date >= '2022-02-15 06:00:00'
        AND maint.asset IS NULL
    ORDER BY 
        sched.sys_created_on ASC
    limit 
        0, 100
```

Comment: Thank you @DRapp my question was not really optimizing the query but why ASC/DESC has a major impact on the query performance, in another word why r_rows have more rows in DESC and high discard rate than  the ASC.

Comment: @YunusSimsek, when ordering, the query needs to qualify and return ALL records first.  Therefore, the ordering is done after to pull the correct limit of 0-100 records.  By having an index to optimize the order by inclusive will help the performance.

Answer (score 0):

This index may help:

```
x_nuvo_eam_scheduled_maintena1:  INDEX(asset, sys_id)
```

We can't see what `idx1 is; please help us.

Are there other differences in the Explains that you did not include?

Did you run each version twice -- to avoid caching differences?